# Want to see if this covariance formula I'm thinking of is correct?

Tags: covariance

In my book, in the section about multiple random variables

I am told that the Covariance of random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ is Cov($X_1,X_2$) = E($X_1X_2)-\mu_1\mu_2$

My question is, is an equivalent form of the above:

Cov($X_1,X_2$) = E($X_1$)E($X_2$) - $\mu_1\mu_2$?

Comment: No. The expected value function is only linear with respect to addition and multiplication by a constant factor. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253546/expected-value-linearity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not always.   That will only occur when $\mathsf E(X_1X_2)=\mathsf E(X_1)\mathsf E(X_2)$, which is the case when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are linearly uncorrelated.

---

Since, $\mu_1=\mathsf E(X_1)$ and $\mu_2=\mathsf E(X_2)$, then $\mathsf E(X_1)\mathsf E(X_2)-\mu_1\mu_2=0$.

Comment: I see so only when independent, got it, thank you!

Comment: No.  They do not need to be independent to be uncorrelated.

Comment: Oh, what are the other conditions then?

Comment: $X_1,X_2$ are uncorrelated exactly when $\mathsf Cov(X_1,X_2)=0$. Therefore $\mathsf E(X_1X_2)=\mathsf E(X_1)\mathsf E(X_2)$ exactly when $X_1,X_2$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: I see, my book seems to just focus on the independence aspect of it though. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Independent random variables are always uncorrelated.  But uncorrelated random variables do not need to be independent.